# Create a for loop which prints every number that is x%%3=0 between 1-200

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Like the title says I need a for loop which will write every number from 1 to 200 that is evenly divided by 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a for loop, use `match` function instead, as in:

```
which(1:200 %% 3 == 0)
 [1]   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36  39  42  45  48  51  54  57  60  63  66  69  72  75  78  81
[28]  84  87  90  93  96  99 102 105 108 111 114 117 120 123 126 129 132 135 138 141 144 147 150 153 156 159 162
[55] 165 168 171 174 177 180 183 186 189 192 195 198
```

Comment: Thank you, that´s even better!

Comment: This is doubly wasteful. It generates 1:200, then mod-3's it, then compares that with 0 creating a vector of TRUE and FALSE. Then `which` has to create another vector of the indexes corresponding to all the TRUEs. Such a senseless waste of electrons...

Comment: @Spacedman If you consider yourself an 'electron saver' then just post another answer and don't make such bad comments. I think this is a matter of respect.

Comment: I think its an important comment - skill in R comes from considering how R works with its vectors, and this is not an efficient method. Just did some benchmarks and generating a vector with `seq` (see my answer) is four times as fast. I think I explained why, so you can learn (which shows respect), and I posted a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

Every other method posted so far generates the 1:200 vector then throws away two thirds of it. What a waste. In an attempt to be eco-conscious, this method does not waste any electrons:

```
seq(3,200,by=3)
```

Comment: +1 - but you are still wasting electrons using numerics when you could use integers.

Answer (score 1):

Two other alternatives:

```
c(1:200)[c(F, F, T)]
c(1:200)[1:200 %% 3 == 0]
```